# Type error: cannot find module body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried making a project on my own and this error happened. I couldn't fix it. It just somehow happens and I am so confused where to start looking for the error.

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminData = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminData.routes);
app.use(shopRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).render('404', { pageTitle: 'Page Not Found' });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

**admin.js**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const rootDir = require('../util/path');

const router = express.Router();

const products = [];

// /admin/add-product => GET
router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('add-product', {
    pageTitle: 'Add Product',
    path: '/admin/add-product',
    formsCSS: true,
    productCSS: true,
    activeAddProduct: true
  });
});

// /admin/add-product => POST
router.post('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  products.push({ title: req.body.title });
  res.redirect('/');
});

exports.routes = router;
exports.products = products;
```

**shop.js**

code snippet of shop.js

[image]

This is my error. 
I am making a webpage for the first time using this.

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\My Website\05-working-on-layout-with-partials\app.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 9):

Please try to install the required body-parser module, 
Use following command to do so.

```
npm install body-parser
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same error message and this fixed it. The answer is now obvious to me, but being new to React I did not know. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please install the dependency i.e `body-parser`

> npm i body-parser  --save

Error is on the 4th line of `app.js` its not getting the `body-parser` module